# Unable to get output after passing functions in node js program?

Tags: node.js

Here is my program

```
function say(word) {
console.log(word);
}
function execute(someFunction, value) {
someFunction(value);
}
execute(say, "Hello");
```

How the value is getting printed through `someFunction(value);`

Comment: The question you originally asked was answered. Please don't modify your question to start asking other questions after you've already gotten an answer that answered the original question. If you have another question, then ask it as another question. Heads up though: what you've been asking shows that you really need to read an introduction on JavaScript and is unlikely to be well received. Stack Overflow is not a site for learning how to program.

Comment: I didn't get the answer i was looking for that's why i edited the post.BTW i know javascript very well but just started learning node js today

Comment: I edited the question kindly remove `onhold` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you meant `execute` to be like this:

```
function execute(someFunction, value) {
    someFunction(value);
}
```

As it is, your code just calls `execute` recursively, forever. (Well, until the stack overflows.)

`word` is not reserved.

Comment: Yes it worked but How `someFunction(value);` is printing this because i am unable to understand it's working

Comment: Are you saying you don't understand how the code works? If it is the case, then I suggest you read an introduction to JavaScript. Stack Overflow is not a site for *learning* how to program.

Comment: No I am asking how `someFunction(value);` is returning output because callback functions returns there output to the function wrapped.